# Consulta sobre un valor string Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

estoy teniendo conflicto con una QUERY en Oracle SQL para encontrar el nombre del archivo.
Entiendo que es tan simple como poner tabla.nombre = 'documento.pdf'.
He intentado con Like y tengo resultados. ¿Alguien me podría ayudar por favor?
Estoy buscando un valor en una columna en una tabla.
Al escribir de esta forma, no me arroja nada mas que las cabeceras de la tabla

FV.NOM_ARCHIVO ='89221_HOMOLOGADOS 89221.pdf'

Si escribo

FV.NOM_ARCHIVO LIKE '%89221%' me aparecen datos que tienen esa cifra y el valor que yo estoy buscando, que es '89221_HOMOLOGADOS 89221.pdf'. Pero al preguntar directo por este valor, no arroja nada.

Gracias de antemano

```
SELECT
distinct CT.COD_CATEGORIA_ARCH,
CT.DESC_CATEGORIA_ARCH,
FV.CORR_FICHA,
TF.COD_TIPO,
DK.DIRECTORIO,
FV.NRO_FICHA || '_' || FV.NOM_ARCHIVO as NOMBRE_ARCHIVO,
FV.DESC_ARCHIVO,
FV.FEC_CARGA,
FV.FECHA_VIGENCIA,
FV.COD_ESTADO,
SUC.NOM_SUC,
F.RUT_CLI AS RUT_CLIENTE,
CL.RAZON_SOCIAL,
FV.NRO_FICHA,
ESTADO_FICHA_VENTA(FV.NRO_FICHA, SYSDATE) || ' - ' || ES.DESC_ESTADO ESTADO_FICHA_VENTA,
(SYSDATE) FECHA_ESTADO_FICHA,
TF.DESCRIPCION_TIPO AS SUBTIPO
FROM
ANEXO_NUMERO_FICHAS FV,
FICHA_VENTA F,
DIR_KSA DK,
TIPO_FICHA_ANEXOS TF,
CLIENTE CL,
SUCURSAL SUC,
CATEGORIA_TIPO_ARCHIVOS CT,
ESTADO ES
WHERE
FV.NRO_FICHA = F.NRO_FICHA
AND DK.COD_SISTEMA = FV.COD_SISTEMA
AND DK.COD_TIPO_DIR = FV.COD_TIPO_DIR
AND TF.COD_TIPO = FV.COD_TIPO
AND F.RUT_CLI = CL.RUT_CLI
AND F.COD_SUC = SUC.COD_SUC
AND TF.COD_CATEGORIA_ARCH = CT.COD_CATEGORIA_ARCH
AND ESTADO_FICHA_VENTA(F.NRO_FICHA, SYSDATE) = ES.COD_ESTADO
AND **FV.NOM_ARCHIVO ='89221_HOMOLOGADOS 89221.pdf'**
```

Comment: Bienvenida a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour] para conocer sobre el funcionamiento del sitio y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. Leo tu pregunta y no me queda claro cual es el problema que tienes, sugiero que expliques con mayor detalle qué es lo que esperas ver o qué es lo que está funcionando mal con tu consulta.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Mi consulta es la siguiente, necesito buscar un valor, un string que es un nombre de archivo para ver todos los datos asociados a el. El nombre de este se encuentra en una de las columnas de la tabla y es asi:

FV.NOM_ARCHIVO ='89221_HOMOLOGADOS 89221.pdf'

 Pero no logro dar con el nombre en la consulta. cuando pongo = 'nombre del archivo.pdf' . Si pongo FV.NOM_ARCHIVO =LIKE ' %89221%' aparece dentro de toda la información que encuentra, pero yo quiero específicamente el que contiene ese nombre.  ¿Se entiende? gracias

Comment: La consulta tiene que encontrarlo. Probablemente estás obviando algún caracter que tiene el nombre del archivo. Sugiero que copies el valor que te devuelve la consulta con `like` y lo pegues en la consulta con `=`. ¿Funciona?

Comment: Gracias @jachguate . No me ha funcionado. Me aparecen las cabeceras de la tabla, sin datos. Por eso preguntaba, pensando que había algo que estaba omitiendo.

Comment: Por favor, copia el valor que te devuelve la consulta con el like y pegalo en la pregunta (no en un comentario, sino edita la pregunta).

Comment: Listo, gracias @jachguate

Comment: A veces ocurre que hay algún caracter _raro_ o _invisible_ en la cadena (por eso pido que copies  pegues), sin embargo esta cadena que pegaste no tiene ninguno. Debiera encontrarlo al hacer la búsqueda.

Comment: Dos recomendaciones. Salvo que estes usando un oracle muy pero muy viejo, aprende a hacer joins explicitos (en lugar del metodo que estas usando)... y luego, verifica la longitud de la cadena, o proba hacerle un trim para ver si no tiene espacios, que es muy probable que no veas en la salida segun el donde estes corriendo la query....

Comment: @gbianchi, ¿a qué se refiere con "joins explícitos"?

Comment: Poner las condiciones de join en el where es antiguo... ahora todas las db aceptan usar la clausula join dentro del from.. fijate en google

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente tenga caracteres extra que no son visibles o que hayan mayúsculas o minúsculas diferentes a valor con el que consulta o tenga espacios extra antes o después

recomiendo usar algo como:

```
AND upper(FV.NOM_ARCHIVO) like upper('%89221_HOMOLOGADOS 89221.pdf%')
```